# Programming Tic Tac Toe in Java with ImageIcons - winningCondition

Tags: java, eclipse, imageicon

I need help because im a beginner in Java programming.
I am programming Tic Tac Toe for University at the moment and i have some problems because i wanted to use some smileys instead of X's & O's. But i don't know how to compare them by Searching for Winners, so i used letters. But you can see the letters together with the Smileys in the playfield and i think this is not the best solution. Maybe some of you have better suggestions and reviews for my program. I copied the images devil.png and sun.png in my TicTacToe src folder.

```
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui implements ActionListener {

    // Variables
    private static int[][] winCombos = new int[][] //Possible win combinations
            {
                {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, //horizontal wins
                {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, //vertical wins
                {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}             //diagonal wins
            };

    static JButton btn[] = new JButton[9];
    private int count = 0;
    private int xscore = 0;
    private int oscore = 0;
    private String letter = "";
    private boolean win = false;
    private ImageIcon devil; // devil= spieler X
    private ImageIcon sun; // sun = spieler O

    public Gui() {

        // Create Window
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        jf.setSize(400, 400);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe Playfield");
        jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        devil = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("devil.png")); //X
        sun = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("sun.png")); //O

        // Add Buttons to the Window
        for (int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
            btn[i] = new JButton();
            btn[i].setVisible(true);
            btn[i].setFocusPainted(false);
            btn[i].addActionListener(this);
            jf.add(btn[i]);
        }
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) 
    {
            count++;

            //Who's turn is it 
            if(count % 2 == 0)
            {
                letter = "O";
                oscore++;
            }
            else
            {
                letter = "X";
                xscore++;
            }

            //Change button to letter
            if(letter == "X")
            {
                JButton pressedButton = (JButton)a.getSource();
                pressedButton.setIcon(devil);
                pressedButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else if(letter == "O")
            {
                JButton pressedButton = (JButton)a.getSource();
                pressedButton.setIcon(sun);
                pressedButton.setEnabled(false);
            }

            //Search for Winner
            for(int i=0; i<=7; i++)
            {
               if(btn[winCombos[i][0]].getIcon() !=null &&
                       btn[winCombos[i][0]].getIcon().equals(btn[winCombos[i][1]].getIcon()) && 
                       btn[winCombos[i][1]].getIcon() !=null && 
                               btn[winCombos[i][1]].getIcon().equals(btn[winCombos[i][2]].getIcon())

                       )

                {
                    win = true;
                }
            }


            //Dialog at the end of the game
            if(win)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " wins the game");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if(count == 9 && !win)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no winner.");
                System.exit(0);
            }               
    }}
```

Comment: So can't you just remove the calls to `setText`, and use `getIcon` instead of `getText` to check the content of a cell?

Comment: Improvement: avoid using `==` when comparing Strings. It will work for literals, but will fail when you are comparing strings generated at runtime (like reading data from file or user from console). Instead use `someText.equals(otherText)`.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, but she's about to remove that line anyway, if she follows my advice.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am not saying to not use your advice. I am just pointing out potential problems in future applications if OP will still be using `==` instead of `equals`.

Comment: Also you don't need `if(win == true)`. Win is already a boolean so you don't need to do the equality check just use the boolean like `if(win)` or `if(!win)`

Comment: Step back for a moment. You need to do is separate the logic from the presentation, this allows you to consistently model the logic and allow the presentation to present in whatever form it wants to. This is the basic functionality of the "model-view-controller" paradigm. With this, you model your data (the game and it's state) and then allow the view (the UI) to present it in what ever manager it wants to. This means the logic for determining when a player wins a game is determined by the model

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Now i changed this line                               for(int i=0; i<=7; i++)
            {
                if( btn[winCombinations[i][0]].getIcon().equals(btn[winCombinations[i][1]].getIcon()) && 
                    btn[winCombinations[i][1]].getIcon().equals(btn[winCombinations[i][2]].getIcon()) && 
                    btn[winCombinations[i][0]].getIcon() !=null)
                {
                    win = true;
                }       and i changed to if(win) and if(!win) but the winning condition doesnt get true anymore for the diagonal.

Comment: Add edits to your question by editing the question so they are easy to read and also so people new to reading the question see the most up to date code you have

Comment: Please don't remove all the code from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MadProgrammers advice here

> Step back for a moment. You need to do is separate the logic from the presentation, this allows you to consistently model the logic and allow the presentation to present in whatever form it wants to. This is the basic functionality of the "model-view-controller" paradigm. With this, you model your data (the game and it's state) and then allow the view (the UI) to present it in what ever manager it wants to. This means the logic for determining when a player wins a game is determined by the model

is definitely the right way to go and the how you should consider designing future projects. However I assume that you perhaps are yet to cover MVC and other design patterns in your course.

The problem you are now getting will be `NullPointerException` in your loop as on the first click most of the buttons will have no icon assigned, so when you then try to call `.equals()` on that null object the exception occurs.

So the simple fix is you will need to check for null icons before you can do the equality check.

**Edit** Before you call the equals!

```
if(btn[winCombinations[i][0]].getIcon() != null && 
   btn[winCombinations[i][0]].getIcon().equals(....
```

You will also need to do this for `btn[winCombinations[i][1]].getIcon()`

**End Edit**

A more concise way might be to use the [`Objects.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) method if you are able

To explain more: When the Exception occurs, the method breaks - so it occurs in your for loop so then the code below that will not get executed. Try adding this below your loop:

```
System.out.println("Reached here!");
```

And you will notice that it is only ever printed once all the buttons have been pressed.

And to help you check more visually, you could add a try catch around your loop - note that this is not ideal operation - but will help you diagnose the problem more visually.

```
try
{
    // your win check loop
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oh no!:\n" + e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts and for the quick responses but actually i don't know what to change in my code. In my equality check i check for null icons. I updated my Code in my question, but the winning condition doesn't work without the letters. And yes you're right its only ever printed once all the buttons have been pressed.

Comment: Your current null check is only occurring for the first button in the win condition and is also the last condition in the statement. It needs to be before you do any further method calls on the same object. The conditions are evaluated in order and if one fails then the rest are not checked. Look at my update above.

Comment: Thank you very very much! It worked without the letter!

Comment: That's good. Please consider marking this answer as accepted if you believe it has helped you solve your problem.